# How to use the Ionic framework Routing method in my React project which is already existing

Tags: reactjs

I want to implement the Ionic routing animations in my react.js project for that I want to add the ionic routing method in my react project please guide me

I tried but it shows IonRouter.displayName = 'IonRouter'; error: ERROR in ./node_modules/@ionic/react-router/dist/index.js 890:18-28
export 'withRouter' (imported as 'withRouter') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, UNSAFE_FetchersContext, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, UNSAFE_ViewTransitionContext, UNSAFE_useRouteId, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, redirectDocument, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_usePrompt, unstable_useViewTransitionState, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useBlocker, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.